# How can I draw overlapping graphics in d3.js?

Tags: d3.js

I can easily draw single elements in an svg and let them overlay using d3, but I somehow cannot combine joint data with drawn graphics.

```
svg = d3.select("#widget").append("svg")
    .attr("width","360")
    .attr("height","240")
svg.append("rect")
    .attr("width","360")
    .attr("height","40")
    .attr("fill","#EDA939")
dataset = [40,50,60,90,30]
svg.selectAll("rect")
    .data(dataset)
    .enter()
    .append("rect")
    .attr("height",5)
    .attr("width",5)
    .attr("x",function(d){return d;})
```

[image]
[image]
**Unfortunately, one element of my array is missing!** It seems that the placeholder in the svg has been consumed by my background svg.

Now I can switch `svg.selectAll("rect")` with `d3.select("#widget").append("svg").selectAll("rect")` so that there is a second svg element, but then I get this:

[image]
[image]

**So either one element is missing and they overlay correctly or they do not overlay and all elements are drawn.**

What can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The background rect is being 'consumed' by the d3 selection because you map your data to all of the rects in the element with `svg.selectAll('rect').data(data)`. When you then use the `.enter()` method, it selects all of the bits of data you have that don't already have a matching DOM element. Since one of your data has a matching DOM element, that one is not in the selection provided by `.enter()`.

To fix this, all you need to do is change the selection from `rect` to something that describes only your data, such as a class. Try this instead:

```
svg.selectAll(".rectClass")
  .data(dataset)
  .enter()
  .append("rect")
  .classed('rectClass', true)
  .attr("height",5)
  .attr("width",5)
  .attr("x",function(d){return d;})
```

Comment: So simple and elegant. Thank you!